# Add callouts to custom infoMarkerWindow implementations for GMSMapview

Tags: uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google IOS SDK and have implemented

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

to implement a custom view. When I show this view, it does not add a callout as Google map view normally does for its own markers. Can anyone please let me know how it would be possible to add this callout like pointer pointing towards the marker for this custom makerInfoWindow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to do it.

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    int popupWidth = 300;
    int contentWidth = 280;
    int contentHeight = 140;
    int contentPad = 10;
    int popupHeight = 200;
    int popupBottomPadding = 16;
    int popupContentHeight = contentHeight - popupBottomPadding;
    int buttonHeight = 30;
    int anchorSize = 20;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D anchor = marker.position;
    CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:anchor];


    UIView *outerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, popupWidth, popupHeight)];
    float offSet = anchorSize * M_SQRT2;
    CGAffineTransform rotateBy45Degrees = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4); //rotate by 45 degrees
    UIView *callOut = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((popupWidth - offSet)/2.0, popupHeight - offSet, anchorSize, anchorSize)];
    callOut.transform = rotateBy45Degrees;
    callOut.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [outerView addSubview:callOut];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, popupWidth, 190)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;



    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(contentPad, 0, contentWidth, 22)];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];
    titleLabel.text = [marker title];

    UILabel *descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(contentPad, 24, contentWidth, 80)];
    [descriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
    descriptionLabel.text = [marker snippet];

    [view addSubview:titleLabel];
    [view addSubview:descriptionLabel];


    [outerView addSubview:view];

    return outerView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is a `GMSMapViewDelegate` method, did you set the delegate to the view controller?

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yes,its showing the custom view - but my question is how to show the little callout marker that google shows for its own marker ...

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you were talking about? I am a little confused about the callout marker you are talking about. And maybe it's better you provide some code of your makerInforWindow method, so we can figure out what the problem is...

Comment: I have it figured out, I will post the code. What I was talking about is to show that little triangle at the bottom pointing to the marker to give a visual indication that this infowindow belongs to this specific marker. I am creating a small view with code and doing an affine transform to make it look like a triangle at the bottom.