# Infowindow Google map ios SDK for route walking distance

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using google ios SDK to show direction in my app.I have plotted two points and shown info for corresponding points using folowing code.

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:9.96 longitude:76.31 zoom:12];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
_mapView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_mapView];

_markerStart = [GMSMarker new];
_markerStart.title = @"Sreeni";
_markerStart.snippet=@"2Km";
_markerStart.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Now i want to show an info window to show distance between each points and an image of walking object.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Info Window for Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps) or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17660940/1597744

Comment: These links represent info window at marker position, i need info window at middle of polyline

Comment: There is no any specific method or property for polyline, you have to show some custom view for this.